# R Save a excel workbook with password protection

Tags: r, excel, xlconnect

I'm a bit impressed because I couldn't find an answer so far.

I have a small R script that is loading data from one source and writing a few dozens Excel files from it. The problem now is: those files need a password protection.

Currently my script is using the [XLConnect](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XLConnect/index.html) library to save the excel files. The script is something like this:

```
# Load data from source
source = <connection string to source>
dataFromSource = <read from source>

# Process
for (data in dataFromSource) {
    wb = loadWorkbook( paste("myWorkbook", sourceName, ".xlsx"), create = TRUE)
    createSheet(wb, name = "sheet")
    <put data into the "sheet">
    saveWorkbook(wb)
}
```

So, making it simple: **how do I create an Excel file with password protection in R?**

Comment: Hi Rick, did my answer provide the help you were looking for?

Comment: @Dale Sorry man, by the time you answered I didn't need it anymore. But I will try to create a small demo to check your solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You should specify whether you're looking to protect an entire workbook or a single sheet. If you're looking to password protect a single sheet, you can use the following rJava function (before saving the workbook):

```
rJava::.jcall(wb$getSheet("Sheet1"),"V","protectSheet", "MyPassword123")
xlsx::saveWorkbook(wb,"C:/myfilepath)
```

The ".jcall" function applies the password to the indicated sheet within the workbook. The "rJava" library must be installed and working properly for this to work.

**Note**

This function only works when using the XLSX package to manipulate Excel files in R. I worked with XLConnect to write the files initially, then, using XLSX, read them back in, apply password protection, and re-save the files to the same path.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to a file archiver and can't install `rJava`, a possible workaround that also works with other output formats is to save the files as usual and then archive them with password protection.

E.g. using 7-zip:

```
setwd("c:/Program Files/7-Zip/")
pwd <- "123"
shell(paste0("7z a d:/Data/myfile.zip d:/Data/myfile.xlsx -p", pwd))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Overview

After reading [How do I password-protect an Excel file created in R with write.xlsx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50867641/how-do-i-password-protect-an-excel-file-created-in-r-with-write-xlsx?noredirect=1&lq=1), it seems versioning of certain packages is at play here.

This might be particular to someone's environment, but this solution just helped a colleague and I write a `data.frame` to a password protected `.xlsx` file:

```
# install necessary packages -----
# note: downloading the latest versions of all packages from CRAN
install.packages(c("XLConnect", "XLConnectJars", "rJava", "xlsx", "openxlsx"))

# attach necessary packages ----
library(XLConnect)

# load but do not attach the write.xlsx() function from the xlsx package ----
xlsx::write.xlsx(x = mtcars, file = "mtcars.xlsx", password = "1234_fghj")

# confirm that the .xlsx file is password protected ----
openxlsx::openXL("mtcars.xlsx")

# session info ----
sessionInfo()
# R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
# Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
# Running under: Red Hat Enterprise Linux
# 
# Matrix products: default
# BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so
# 
# locale:
# [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8         
# [2] LC_NUMERIC=C                 
# [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8          
# [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8       
# [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8      
# [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8      
# [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8         
# [8] LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8          
# [9] LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8       
# [10] LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8     
# [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8   
# [12] LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
# 
# attached base packages:
# [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
# [6] methods   base     
# 
# other attached packages:
# [1] XLConnect_0.2-15     XLConnectJars_0.2-15
# 
# loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
# [1] compiler_3.5.1 tools_3.5.1    yaml_2.2.0    
# [4] xlsxjars_0.6.1 rJava_0.9-10   xlsx_0.6.1
```