# How do I password-protect an Excel file created in R with write.xlsx?

Tags: r, excel, encryption, passwords

In my data analysis in `R` I sometimes output data to Excel files using `write.xlsx`.  These files need to be password-protected, and currently I am doing this by opening the unprotected file using Excel, and then adding a password using `File - Protect Workbook - Encrypt with Password`.

Is there a way to do this directly in `R` so that I don't have to open the Excel file and manually add the password?  (I want to password-protect the whole workbook, not just a single sheet.)

Comment: You could try out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991389/r-save-a-excel-workbook-with-password-protection

Comment: The (now deleted) answer from @DTYK suggested using the `password` argument to `write.xlsx`. However, you said that you got an `unused argument` error when you tried this. You might just need to update the package. The latest version of `xlsx` is 0.6.1, released on June 7, 2018, in which [`write.xlsx` has a `password` argument](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsx/xlsx.pdf). I happen to have `xlsx` version 0.5.7 installed at the moment and there's no `password` argument in that version.

Comment: @eipi10 Thanks for the heads-up (I un-deleted my answer). After re-installing the xlsx package, indeed write.xlsx has the password argument.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the xlsx manual, you can set the password in the password argument:

```
write.xlsx(x, file, sheetName="Sheet1", col.names=TRUE, row.names=TRUE, append=FALSE, showNA=TRUE, password=NULL)
```

Comment: I just tried this, by setting a password character string ```PASS```, and it came back with an error message - ```Error in write.xlsx(... : unused argument (password = PASS)```.

Comment: @Ben You might want to try re-installing the xlsx package. The latest update for the package has the password argument for `write.xlsx`.